# Sequence of tense in German translations of a Camus sentence

Tags: tense

The question concerns these German translations of the opening sentence of Book I chapter 2 of The Stranger by Camus.

I am quoting more in the first translation than in the second for context. Meursault, the narrator, is recalling a conversation he had with his boss a few days before.

Uli Aumüller:

> (A0) Als ich aufwachte, **ist mir klargeworden**, warum mein Chef verstimmt **aussah**, als ich ihn um zwei Tage Urlaub **gebeten habe**: heute ist Sonnabend.  Ich hatte es sozusagen vergessen, aber beim Aufstehen ist es mir eingefallen. Mein Chef hat natürlich gedacht, daß ich so mit meinem Sonntag vier Tage Urlaub hätte, und das konnte ihn nicht freuen. Aber einerseits ist es nicht meine Schuld, daß man Mama gestern und nicht heute beerdigt hat, und andererseits hätte ich auf alle Fälle meinen Sonnabend und meinen Sonntag gehabt. Selbstverständlich kann ich meinen Chef deswegen trotzdem verstehen.

Georg Goyert und Hans Georg Brenner:

> (G0) Als ich erwachte, **wurde** mir klar, weshalb mein Chef so unwirsch **war**, als ich ihn um zwei Tage Urlaub **bat**: heute ist Samstag.

**QUESTION**

Is there an option to change the sentences as follows without making them ungrammatical or changing their meaning?

> (A1) Als ich aufwachte, **ist mir klargeworden**, warum mein Chef verstimmt **ausgesehen hatte**, als ich ihn um zwei Tage Urlaub **gebeten habe**: heute ist Sonnabend.

and

> (G1) Als ich erwachte, **wurde** mir klar, weshalb mein Chef so unwirsch **gewesen war**, als ich ihn um zwei Tage Urlaub **bat**: heute ist Samstag.

or

> (A2) Als ich aufwachte, **ist mir klargeworden**, warum mein Chef verstimmt **ausgesehen hatte**, als ich ihn um zwei Tage Urlaub **gebeten hatte**: heute ist Sonnabend.

and

> (G2) Als ich erwachte, **wurde** mir klar, weshalb mein Chef so unwirsch **gewesen war**, als ich ihn um zwei Tage Urlaub **gebeten hatte**: heute ist Samstag.

Note that (A1) and (G1) would match the English translations below.

Whatever else you may do, please say definite yes or no to the four sentences above.

**Background**

The French original and some English translations.

> En me réveillant, j’**ai compris** pourquoi mon patron **avait** l’air mécontent quand je lui **ai demandé** mes deux jours de congé : c’est aujourd’hui samedi.  Je l’avais pour ainsi dire oublié, mais en me levant, cette idée m’est venue. Mon patron, tout naturellement, a pensé que j’aurais ainsi quatre jours de vacances avec mon dimanche et cela ne pouvait pas lui faire plaisir. Mais d’une part, ce n’est pas de ma faute si on a enterré maman hier au lieu d’aujourd’hui et d’autre part, j’aurais eu mon samedi et mon dimanche de toute façon. Bien entendu, cela ne m’empêche pas de comprendre tout de même mon patron.

Stuart Gilbert:

> ON WAKING I **understood** why my employer **had looked** rather cross when I **asked** for my two days off; it’s a Saturday today.

Matthew Ward:

> As I was waking up, it **came** to me why my boss **had seemed** annoyed when I **asked** him for two days off:  Today is Saturday.

I have put a [related question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23386/sequence-of-tense-involving-imperfect-and-simple-past) to the French StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

> (G1) Als ich erwachte, wurde mir klar, weshalb mein Chef so unwirsch **gewesen war**, als ich ihn um zwei Tage Urlaub bat: heute ist Samstag.

This sounds strange to me. It means that the at the time of the speaker asking for vacation, the boss had been "unwirsch" at some earlier time in the past. He had already finished being "unwirsch" which is wrong. The boss was "unwirsch" at the time the speaker asked for vacation.

The same can probably said about (A1) where "ausgesehen hatte" means that the boss already finished looking "verstimmt".

Comment: Thank you. But in English, the boss had indeed finished looking cross by the time Meursault (narrator) understood or realized why (which happened days later); hence *had looked*. German however ignores this bit? If yes, I would want to say that (grammatical) aspect was triumphing over sequence of tense rules in German.

Comment: Yes, by the time the narrator understood what happend, but not at the time the boss looked.